# Why can't I unset the executable bit on my files in a Veracrypt vfat partition?

Tags: permissions, fat32, veracrypt

In a mounted Veracrypt file, which `df -Th` shows to be `vfat`, my files are always executable. 
`$ ls -l x.txt`
gives
`-rwx------ ... x.txt`
How do I make it not-executable? `chmod -x x.txt` doesn't work, not even with `sudo`; nor with `u-x`, `a-x` `g-x` etc; nor  does `chmod 400 x.txt`

In Nautilus too, I cannot change this.

Is this behavior normal?

(Possibly related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-mount/+bug/78505).)

Comment: Seems likely to be related to veracrypt as the default for vfat in Ubuntu thru udisks2 includes the showexec option, i.e only .exe file will be seen as executable. (- unlike the current default for ntfs which sees all files as executable..) `mount` will show you the mount options for your mounted volumes..

Comment: @doug good one. Have some upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this behavior normal?

Yes. VFAT is not a POSIX-style filesystem. Neither are NTFS, exFat, FAT.  Why do you expect Microsoft to follow Linux/Unix permissions?

> my files are always executable.

No, your -mount point- is set executable. As this is a Microsoft filesystem all Linux styled options (user, group, read, write, execute, etc) are set when mounting.

> How do I make it not-executable?

Don't mount it executable.

man page [mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html):

> showexec
>
> If  set,  the  execute  permission  bits  of  the  file will be allowed only if the extension part of the name is .EXE, .COM, or .BAT. Not set by default.